# Azure web app deployment failure: access denied for NuGet package

Tags: azure, github, .net-core, nuget, kudu

I'm attempting to deploy a .NET Core web app in Azure on Linux from GitHub using Kudu. I get this error during deployment:

```
Command: "/home/site/deployments/tools/deploy.sh"
Handling ASP.NET Core Web Application deployment.
  Restoring packages for /home/site/repository/myproject.csproj...
  Installing NuGet.Frameworks 4.7.0.
/opt/dotnet/2.2.104/sdk/2.2.104/NuGet.targets(114,5): error : Access to the path '/var/nuget/nuget.frameworks/4.7.0' is denied. [/home/site/repository/myproject.csproj]
/opt/dotnet/2.2.104/sdk/2.2.104/NuGet.targets(114,5): error :   Permission denied [/home/site/repository/myproject.csproj]
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
dotnet restore failed
\n/opt/Kudu/Scripts/starter.sh "/home/site/deployments/tools/deploy.sh"
```

`NuGet.Frameworks` is not a library I use in my project. How can I get my project to successfully deploy?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the package `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design` from the project. It has many dependencies, including `NuGet.Frameworks`, and doesn't seem to play nice with Azure (at least on Linux).